# Contract should be marked as abstract ( Missing implementation)

Tags: solidity

Hello i am getting error on line 4 `TypeError: Contract "Token" should be marked as abstract.`
I know there was a lot threads made about this before but none of them seems to give me solution .

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Token {

    mapping(address => uint256) AccountsBalances; // Token accounts 
    string public constant TokenName = "NewToken";
    string public constant TokenSymbol = "ALPH";
    uint public  MaxTokens = 1000000000;
    uint256 public constant decimals = 18;

    function transfer(address _to,uint256 _amount) virtual payable public  returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address _from , address _to ,uint _amount) virtual payable public returns (bool);
    function AllowToSpend( address _spender , uint256 _allowanceAmount) virtual public returns (bool);
    function CheckMyAllowance(address _walletAddress) virtual public view returns (uint256);
    function BalanceOfWallet(address _walletAddress) virtual public view returns (uint256);
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event ApprovalToSpend(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);
}


contract StandardToken is Token{

    
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) Allowed;// Allowance count


    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _amount)override payable public returns (bool){
        if(AccountsBalances[msg.sender] >= _amount && _amount > 0 && msg.sender != _to)
        {
            AccountsBalances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
            AccountsBalances[_to] += _amount;
            Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _amount);
        } else return false;
    }


    function transferFrom(address _TransferFrom , address _TransferTo , uint256 _amount)override payable public returns (bool)
    {
        if(CheckMyAllowance(_TransferFrom) >= _amount && AccountsBalances[_TransferFrom] >= _amount && _amount > 0)
        {
            AccountsBalances[_TransferFrom] -= _amount;
            Allowed[_TransferFrom][msg.sender] -= _amount;
            AccountsBalances[_TransferTo] += _amount;
            Transfer(_TransferFrom,_TransferTo,_amount);
        }else return false;
    }

    function AllowToSpend(address _spender,uint256 _allowanceAmount) override public returns (bool)
    {
        Allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _allowanceAmount;
        ApprovalToSpend(msg.sender,_spender,_allowanceAmount);
        return true;
    }

    function CheckMyAllowance(address _walletAddress) override public view returns (uint256)
    {
        return Allowed[_walletAddress][msg.sender];
    }


    function BalanceOfWallet(address _walletAddress)override public view returns (uint256)
    {
        require(CheckMyAllowance(_walletAddress) > 0, "You have no allowance on this account and cannot see balance");
        return AccountsBalances[_walletAddress];
    }
}
```

I was reading other posts about this issue but none of them seems to help me find solution for this .

Comment: Sorry for the wrong edit, I confused your code with the corrected version I sent you and though I made a mistake, I rolled it back, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://solidity-fr.readthedocs.io/fr/latest/contracts.html?highlight=abstract#abstract-contracts) :

> Contracts need to be marked as abstract when at least one of their
> functions is not implemented. Contracts may be marked as abstract even
> though all functions are implemented.

Since `Token` has no implementation you must mark it as abstract.

You also have some issues on your event related syntax and some potential bugs when returning default boolean values in your `transferFrom` and `transfer` functions.

Here is a corrected version of your code :

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

abstract contract Token {

    mapping(address => uint256) AccountsBalances; // Token accounts 
    string public constant TokenName = "NewToken";
    string public constant TokenSymbol = "ALPH";
    uint public  MaxTokens = 1000000000;
    uint256 public constant decimals = 18;

    function transfer(address _to,uint256 _amount) virtual payable public  returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address _from , address _to ,uint _amount) virtual payable public returns (bool);
    function AllowToSpend( address _spender , uint256 _allowanceAmount) virtual public returns (bool);
    function CheckMyAllowance(address _walletAddress) virtual public view returns (uint256);
    function BalanceOfWallet(address _walletAddress) virtual public view returns (uint256);
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event ApprovalToSpend(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);
}


contract StandardToken is Token{

    
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) Allowed;// Allowance count


    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _amount) override payable public returns (bool){
        if(AccountsBalances[msg.sender] >= _amount && _amount > 0 && msg.sender != _to)
        {
            AccountsBalances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
            AccountsBalances[_to] += _amount;
            emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _amount);
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }


    function transferFrom(address _TransferFrom , address _TransferTo , uint256 _amount)override payable public returns (bool)
    {
        if(CheckMyAllowance(_TransferFrom) >= _amount && AccountsBalances[_TransferFrom] >= _amount && _amount > 0)
        {
            AccountsBalances[_TransferFrom] -= _amount;
            Allowed[_TransferFrom][msg.sender] -= _amount;
            AccountsBalances[_TransferTo] += _amount;
            emit Transfer(_TransferFrom,_TransferTo,_amount);
            return true;
        }else return false;
    }

    function AllowToSpend(address _spender,uint256 _allowanceAmount) override public returns (bool)
    {
        Allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _allowanceAmount;
        emit ApprovalToSpend(msg.sender,_spender,_allowanceAmount);
        return true;
    }

    function CheckMyAllowance(address _walletAddress) override public view returns (uint256)
    {
        return Allowed[_walletAddress][msg.sender];
    }


    function BalanceOfWallet(address _walletAddress)override public view returns (uint256)
    {
        require(CheckMyAllowance(_walletAddress) > 0, "You have no allowance on this account and cannot see balance");
        return AccountsBalances[_walletAddress];
    }
}
```

If you are writing this for learning that's fine (just make sure to match the [EIP-20 specifications](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20)), otherwise consider using well tested implementations such as the ones from [OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts). The one that would suit you the best is probably the [ERC-20 implementation](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/master/contracts/token/ERC20).

Comment: Okay i see those mistakes i made now ... I was writing this both for learning and possible use case .but i will look into ERC20 thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since the `Token` contract has functions that have no implementation, the contract needs to be marked as `abstract`. An abstract contract is a contract written for development purposes only and is not meant to be deployed but extended by other contracts that override the unimplemented functions.

The `Token` contract could be marked as abstract as follows:

```
abstract contract Token {
...
```